# Analytic lower-bound for minimal value of $\|x\|^2$ such that $\|Cx-b\|^2 \le c^2$ (a hyperellipsoid)

Tags: pr.probability, convex-geometry, convex-optimization, euclidean-geometry, lower-bounds

Let $C$ be an  $n \times p$ matrix and $b$ be a column vector of length $n$, and $c>0$. Let $E := \{x \in \mathbb R^p \mid \|Cx-b\| \le c\}$, a hyperellipsoid in nonstandard position.

> **Question 1.** What is a good **analytic lower-bound** for the quantity $\theta:=\underset{\|Cx-b\| \le c}{\inf} \|x\|^2$, say in terms of $c$, the singular-values of $C$, etc. ?

Note that this is the (squared) distance between E and the origin.

> **Question 2.** Same question when $c=t\sqrt{n}$ with $t \in (0, 1)$, $C$ is a random matrix with rows independent iid rows from $N(0,1/p)$ and $b$ is a random vector with iid entries from $N(0,1)$, and independent of $C$. The question is then above high-probability lower-bounds for $\theta$.

### Notes

The case when $b$ is the zero vector has been solved here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2090988/168758. However, tbe general case seems to require a completely different argument / technique.